# Fuzzy Searching with Mongodb: No results

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, express, search

I have implemented fuzzy searching using regex as shown below. I'm trying to figure out how to display something if no results are found from the search. How would I display: "No results found." If none are found?

Thanks!

```
function escapeRegex(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    if (req.query.search) {
       const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
       Jobs.find({ "name": regex }, function(err, foundjobs) {
           if(err) {
               console.log(err);
           } else {
              res.render("jobs/index", { jobs: foundjobs });
           }
if (foundjobs.length === 0){
  res.render('jobs/none'); 
  }
       }); 
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I added the code:

```
 if (foundjobs.length === 0){
      res.render('jobs/none'); 
      }
```

**This works but I get an error of "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."**

Comment: Either render a different page, or check on the page? It's not clear to me where in the thought process you're having difficulty.

Comment: Since you have a `gi` on the regex, if you are using it to make an array, couldn't you just test the array size ? What is `foundjobs` ?

Comment: Both very helpful comments thank you!

Comment: @DaveNewton  - I updated the code and it works well. One issue. Now I get an error of "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." Any thoughts? See updated code.

Comment: @sln code updated